# How to open Edge to a specific page from the command line?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have installed Microsoft Edge, and Edge (dev mode). Every time I try to open edge with command line, `start microsoft-edge:http://www.example.com/`, it just launches the Edge (Dev Mode) with about blank tab, the URL passed is not getting opened.

I want to keep both Edge and Edge (dev) and also wanted to launch through command line. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open Edge(dev) with URL using the following command:

```
start msedge "http://www.example.com/"
```

You can open Edge with URL using the following command:

```
start microsoft-edge:http://www.example.com/
```